# Is CMD in parent docker overriden by CMD/ENTRYPOINT in child docker image?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image

I am trying to get my hands dirty on docker. I know that `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` is used to specify the start/runnable command for docker image and `CMD` is overridden by `ENTRYPOINT`. But I don't know, how does it works, when parent docker image, also has `CMD` OR `ENTRYPOINT` or BOTH ?

Does child image inherit those values from parent docker image ? If so, then does `ENTRYPOINT` in parent image override `CMD` in child image ?

I know that such question is already discussed at https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3140. But, the discussion is quite old(before 2-3 years) and it doesn't answer my question clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you define an `ENTRYPOINT` in a child image, it will null out the value of `CMD` as identified in [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5147). The goal is to avoid a confusing situation where an entrypoint is passed as args a command you no longer want to run.

Other than this specific situation, the value of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are inherited and can be individually overridden by a child image or even a later step of the same Dockerfile. Only one value for each of these will ever exist in an image with the last defined value having precedence.

Comment: So, if I have image#3(which have CMD and ENTRYPOINT), which inherits image#2(which have CMD only), which inherits from image#1(which have both CMD and ENTRYPOINT), what will be the effective runnable command for image#3 ?

Comment: image#3 will have the CMD and ENTRYPOINT you define in image#3. If you define both, it doesn't matter what values were defined before, there's only one value for each of these fields, there is no built in chaining.

Answer (score 6):

ENTRYPOINT doesn't override CMD, they just represent to parts of resulting command and exist to make life easier. Whenever container is started, the command for process 1 is determined as ENTRYPOINT + CMD, so usually ENTRYPOINT is just path to the binary and CMD is a list of arguments for that binary. CMD can also be easily overriden from command line.

So, again, it's just a thing to make life easier and make containers behave just like regular binaries - if you have `man` container, you can set entrypoint to `/usr/bin/man` and cmd to `man`. So if you just start container, docker will execute `/usr/bin/man man`, but if you run something like `docker run man docker`, the resulting container command will be `/usr/bin/man docker` - the entrypoint stays the same, cmd changes, and resulting command to start container is just a simple merging of those.

ENTRYPOINT and CMD are both inherited from parent layers (images) unless overriden, so if you inherit from image X and redefine CMD, you will still have the very same ENTRYPOINT <del>and vice versa</del>. However, as @BMitch mentioned below, changing ENTRYPOINT in child image will effectively reset CMD.