# Docker: Entrypoint's override involve CMD specification?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

That's a question for my pure curiousity:

I have to personalize a Docker Image, in particular this is an extract of my dockerfile:

```
ARG DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION
FROM php:${DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION:+${DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine
# RUN some personal stuff
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html

# Set proper Entrypoint
COPY build/fs/usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "my-entrypoint.sh" ]

WORKDIR /var/www
```

and `my-entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo "Trying my-entrypoint with args: $@"

if [ ! -z "$XDEBUG_ENABLED" ] ; then
    echo "Enabling XDEBUG"
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
fi

# execute default entrypoint
echo "Execute Main:"
docker-php-entrypoint $@
echo "Main Done"
```

the original image is `PHP-FPM-ALPINE` that has the command

```
CMD [ "php-fpm" ]
```

My problem is that when i run this image (ok, we properly run containers, not images, I know) the default command is not passed to `my-entrypoint.sh`, in fact the output is:

```
Trying my-entrypoint with args: 
Enabling XDEBUG
Execute Main:
Main Done
```

That is the ENTRYPOINT doesn't receive the default command `php-fpm`, and so the main process automatically stops.

BUT if I modify the dockerfile adding the `CMD` at the end:

```
ARG DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION
FROM php:${DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION:+${DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine
# RUN some personal stuff
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html

# Set proper Entrypoint
COPY build/fs/usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/my-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "my-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD ["php-fpm"]

WORKDIR /var/www
```

and all goes right (that is the CMD is passed to entrypoint):

```
Trying my-entrypoint with args: php-fpm
Enabling XDEBUG
Execute Main:
```

#### Finally my question:

why I have to redeclare the `CMD ["php-fpm"]` if I change the `ENTRYPOINT` directive?

> note that `CMD ["php-fpm"]` is the same in original IMAGE.

Comment: Without having CMD [ "php-fpm" ] in your docker file can you `docker exec -it containerName sh` for me and check what docker-php-entrypoint is, should be located somewhere like /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint. Presumably this is changing, compare the differences. Else, try outputting exactly what $@ is to see what's the difference is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is CMD in parent docker overriden by CMD/ENTRYPOINT in child docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49028644/596285)

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the exception cases when inheriting values from a previous image. If the parent image defines a `CMD`, and your image defines an `ENTRYPOINT`, then the value of `CMD` is nulled out. In all other scenarios, you should see `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` inherited from parent images unchanged. For the logic behind this decision, please see [issue 5147](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5147).