# Docker override ENTRYPOINT but keep CMD

Tags: docker

I need to extend a base image (jwilder/nginx-proxy) because I need to add some additional configuration to that image.

Some of these configuration changes need to be done during the container's runtime, before the logic of the base image starts.

The way that I have implemented that runtime configuration is by creating a custom ENTRYPOINT file that first does all my custom work and then starts the base image's entrypoint.

My entrypoint looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# my custom logic here

echo "Executed custom logic."

# default jwilder/nginx entrypoint
/app/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Currently, this does not work because "$@" resolves to nothing. My custom Dockerfile does not set a custom CMD, only the ENTRYPOINT.

Is there a reason why this does not work? I would have hoped that the base images's CMD remains set and is passed to my ENTRYPOINT. Otherwise I need to copy the base image's CMD which is prone to errors if that CMD ever changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53298532/596285

Answer (score 3):

From the docs

> If CMD is defined from the base image, setting ENTRYPOINT will reset
> CMD to an empty value. In this scenario, CMD must be defined in the
> current image to have a value.

This goes for CMD as well. CMD and ENTRYPOINT resets any CMD or ENTRYPOINT values from the base image.

You have to set it yourself again.

If you're concerned about the value changing - and the base image is under your control - you could set an environment variable instead and use that.

Comment: That is quite unfortunate. I do not have control over the base image.

Comment: OTOH, it would also be a shaky assumption that if the CMD in the base image changes, that the ENTRYPOINT wouldn't need to be changed/updated at the same time.

Comment: That is true. However, I have not copied the entrypoint file. I have simply created my own that calls the base image's entrypoint file. So problems only arise if and when the location of that entrypoint file changes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `CMD` from the base would be removed as noted in the [builder reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example). The `CMD` could be included in your `Dockerfile` along with your new `ENTRYPOINT`.

https://hub.docker.com/layers/jwilder/nginx-proxy/latest/images/sha256-876a1df7bf88bb801cef813b276e4ee8c1861fca4c47cfaaeb2e7d3a087c4360?context=explore indicates that the `CMD` would be `CMD ["forego" "start" "-r"]`.

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest

COPY /new-entrypoint.sh /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/new-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["forego", "start", "-r"]
```

should produce:

```bash
docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro test | head
```

```
Executed custom logic.
Info: running nginx-proxy version 1.3.1-34-gc430825
Setting up DH Parameters..
Warning: TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY is not set; defaulting to "true". For security, you should explicitly set TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY to "false" if there is not a trusted reverse proxy in front of this proxy.
Warning: The default value of TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY might change to "false" in a future version of nginx-proxy. If you require TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY to be enabled, explicitly set it to "true".
forego      | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego      | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:50:39 [notice] 21#21: using the "epoll" event method
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:50:39 [warn] 21#21: 10240 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
nginx.1     | nginx: [warn] 10240 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:50:39 [notice] 21#21: nginx/1.25.1
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:50:39 [notice] 21#21: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
```

---

Also, as per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ we can use `--entrypoint` with the `docker run` command to override the default `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile and then provide the `CMD` at the end of the `docker run` command.

Example:
Dockerfile

```
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest

COPY /new-entrypoint.sh /app
```

should produce:

```bash
docker run --entrypoint /app/new-entrypoint.sh -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro test forego start -r | head
Executed custom logic.
Info: running nginx-proxy version 1.3.1-34-gc430825
Setting up DH Parameters..
Warning: TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY is not set; defaulting to "true". For security, you should explicitly set TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY to "false" if there is not a trusted reverse proxy in front of this proxy.
Warning: The default value of TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY might change to "false" in a future version of nginx-proxy. If you require TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY to be enabled, explicitly set it to "true".
forego      | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego      | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:53:55 [notice] 22#22: using the "epoll" event method
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:53:55 [warn] 22#22: 10240 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
nginx.1     | nginx: [warn] 10240 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:53:55 [notice] 22#22: nginx/1.25.1
nginx.1     | 2023/07/20 23:53:55 [notice] 22#22: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
```